# knockout.js dynamic field binding with variable

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, computed-observable

Is there a way to dynamically replace the field being written to and read from in the ko.computed? For example, with this function, I want to replace the self.JobStartDate with a variable fieldname that I could pass in:

```
function Job(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this); 

    var computedDateFn = {
        read: function() {
            return formatDate(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.JobStartDate), true);
        },

        write: function(value) {
            var jsonDate = "/Date(" + Date.parse(value).getTime();
            self.JobStartDate(jsonDate);
        }
    }

    this.formattedStartDate = ko.computed(computedDateFn);
    this.formattedEndDate = ko.computed(computedDateFn); // this guy would need the field it writes to/reads from to be self.JobEndDate
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make computedDateFn a function that accepts your fieldname as string and returns the object defining your computed observable, you can use array notation like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/tMTCV/

Comment: This definitely was the answer I'm looking for, except I'm getting self[fieldName] is not a function.  Thoughts?

Comment: That would happen if self.JobEndDate or self.JobStartDate is not observable.  Can you add some context to my fiddle so I can test it?

Comment: I added a subsnippet of one of the job items in JSON.  Notice there's a date field on the job itself, and then 2 date fields on the salary.  I'm currently trying to do this for the ones on the salary field, but I'll also need it done on the job field.  Thanks in advance for your help. In this case "Salary" is a subject on the job.  Can I not path to it by saying "self['Salary.JobStartDate']? I added some updates here: http://jsfiddle.net/xCMnq/1/

Comment: Brian - it totally works on the field directly on the job.  It's the field that's on the .Salary child object that causes the break.

Comment: added more to the html panel - here's the updated fiddle.  notice the data-bind="with: Salary" http://jsfiddle.net/xCMnq/3/

Comment: 2 problems. 1. json is an array of objects and you were passing it the Job constructor as if it were on object so I added a for loop to iterate over the array. 2. You cannot mix bracket notation and dot notation plus you really want your computed to be in the Salary object and not your Job object.  This can all be done by passing some options to the mapping plugin. Here's the updated fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/xCMnq/4/ ...Check the console for the viewmodel. I couldn't get it to work with your view because I don't have the formatDate method.

Comment: Another resounding YES. This was extremely helpful and you very much nailed exactly what I was trying to do.  The last piece of the puzzle is that I'm going to try to get the same function to work for the Job.AcceptedDate so that have no repeat code and I reduce verboseness. Thanks once again!

Comment: Once again, this is really superb and very much the answer I was looking for.  It's a tiny bit unfortunate that it's a little difficult to follow at first glance, but it's very powerful.  Thank you!

Comment: Nothing a few comments can't cure. Nice working with you and good luck.